Center Support for Closet Rod
Hi all I'm new to home improvement but I need some help on my closet. I have a closet that's roughly 8 feet so I'm aware I will need some kind of support in the middle. I was wondering if there is any kind of support mechanisms that don't require a shelf. All I see when I google for closet rod support are the ones that either connect to a wire shelf or drill into a wood one I was just hoping to make this fast and easy and not have to install a shelf and I don't love the wire shelves as well. Any advice would be great. Thank you!

I'm not sure I understand you correctly but why not something like this? https://www.desunia.com/adjustable-bloset-rod-shelf-bracket-finish-white/ The shelving on top is optional.

Also, depending on the height, and availability of a joist, you can use a ceiling hanger—basically a rod with an eye on the bottom and a mounting flange on the top.

@divB, make your comment an answer.  It is the best and easiest solution.
